# Has_and_belong_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, has-and-belongs-to-many, model-associations

I have two models with no associations between them. So, I generated a migration and added an association.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workspaces
end
```

```
class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

```
class CreateJoinTablePostsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :posts, :workspaces do |t|
      # t.index [:post_id, :workspace_id]
      # t.index [:workspace_id, :post_id]
    end
  end
end
```

I currently have a page where all the posts are shown. However, I added a multi select in the post creation form in order to select one workspace or more when creating. I would like to be able to show only the posts that were created for that particular workspace instead of all of them, as it is at the moment.
My controller is as follows:

```
class PostsController < Admin::BaseControlle
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        @posts = Post.all.order(:order)
        render json: present_collection(@posts, PostPresenter).map(&:as_json)
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:label, :url, :active, workspace_ids: [])
  end
end
```

I am able to get the associated workspace this way:

**Post.first.workspaces**

But I would like to show all the posts and I get an error when I try this command:

**Post.all.workspaces**

How could I change my controller and accomplish that? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should have a `table` called `PostsWorkspaces` by rails convention so you should be able to do something like:

```rb
posts_in_workspaces = PostsWorkspaces.all.pluck(:post_id)
Posts.where(id: posts_in_workspaces )
```

The above will return the `posts` that have at least one `workspace` associated, the problem with the approach `Post.all.workspaces` is that not all posts need to have a workspace (or more than one) associated, also you can think on `Post.all` like `select * from posts` which is not what you want to accomplish.

Hope the above helps!

Comment: If you use `select` instead of `pluck` Rails will use a subquery in sql making it more performant.

Comment: yup that is an improvement 

Comment: Happy to help! 

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking about this the wrong way. `Post.first.workspaces` works because the association is applied on the instance of `Post` returned. But `Post.all` returns a collection.

Your best bet is to do something like the following.

```
# Return all posts that have a workspace associated
posts = Post.joins(:workspaces).all.distinct

posts.each do |post|
 post.workspaces
end
```

If you want to include posts without a workspace

```
posts = Post.includes(:workspaces).all

posts.each do |post|
 post.workspaces
end
```